# Hosting classical asp project in local iis 7

Tags: asp-classic, iis-7

I have one classic asp project. and i am trying to host on local IIS7 but i am getting below error when i tried to browse that web application.

An error occurred on the server when processing the URL. Please contact the system administrator.
If you are the system administrator please click here to find out more about this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this guide: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/scenario-build-a-classic-asp-website-on-iis

And this other to show error details: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-script-error-messages-no-longer-shown-in-web-browser-by-default